# Curry-Howard Correspondence using Smullyan's bird forests

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory

I'm having trouble understanding the Wikipedia article on [Simply typed lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus).

And also on the Curry-Howard Isomorphism.  Is there a nice way to put it in bird-forest form like [To Mock a Mocking Bird](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0192801422).
This book made everything so simple and intuitive for me.

Comment: Could you elaborate on which part of the article you are having problems with?

Comment: If you understood what the Wikipedia article says, you wouldn't bother  asking this question. (back at you!)

Comment: A tip: Don't "spit at" newcomers when you're clearly a newbie, yourself!